# Spliterator trySplit return type

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, spliterator

I have stumbled upon an interesting detail in `java.util.Spliterator`  (Java 8).

Method trySplit() is supposed to return an instance of Spliterator or `null`, if it can't be split. The java doc says the following:

```
 * @return a {@code Spliterator} covering some portion of the
 * elements, or {@code null} if this spliterator cannot be split.
```

It appears to me as a perfect place to use `java.util.Optional`. As per javadoc:

```
 * A container object which may or may not contain a non-null value.
```

Are there any reasons, why Optional was not used?

Googling did not help much, except this [question](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/lambda-dev/2012-December/007398.html) in lambda-dev mailing list, which was not answered.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are a couple of reasons it's the way it is. Of course, conceptually, `trySplit` could return `Optional<Spliterator<T>>`, but there are some design forces that pushed away from this.

One reason is that there's a difference between methods such as `findFirst` that return `Optional` vs. methods such as `trySplit` that return value-or-null.

- Methods like `findFirst` are called by and return values to *application* code.
- Methods like `trySplit` are called by and return values to *library* code.

A design aspect of the JDK class libraries is that the library APIs are (or should be) designed to make things easier for application code, and library code will often take on more complexity in order to make things simpler for applications.

One of the main reasons for `Optional` is to avoid passing nulls from the library to application code, because improper null handling is a common source of `NullPointerException`s. Instead of `null`, APIs like `findFirst` will return an empty `Optional`, which is supported by a rich set of methods such as `orElse`, `map`, `filter`, `flatMap`, etc. that provide a great deal of flexibility to applications for dealing with the not-found case.

Note that the nullable return value from `trySplit` is going in the opposite direction: from the application to the library.

Having application code pass or return a nullable value *to the library* is considerably less error-prone for the application than having it receive a nullable value *from the library*. If you're writing an application and the API says that you should pass or return a null to the library, there's no possibility that this will generate an NPE in *your* code. Indeed, there are a variety of places in the APIs (`List.sort(null)` comes to mind) where `null` has particular semantics in the API.

`trySplit` is called from relatively few places in the library, and the library maintainers are taking on the burden of dealing properly with `null` in all of those cases.

Another prime consideration is performance. Splitting is in the critical path of setting up a parallel pipeline. It's performed sequentially, before work is handed off to different threads to be executed in parallel. Per [Amdahl's Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amdahl%27s_law), in order to make parallelism as efficient as possible, you want to minimize the sequential setup overhead.

The fact is that an `Optional` is a box, and there is a cost to boxing and unboxing a value to and from an `Optional`. The JIT compiler *might* be able to optimize this away in some cases, but it might not. Even if it does, there's a period of time where the code is running but the `Optional` hasn't yet been optimized away. That's additional overhead. Since the library code is willing to bear the burden of handling `null` properly, we can guarantee there's no boxing overhead simply by not using `Optional` at all in this case.

Answer (score 7):

`Spliterator` is the part of internal stream implementation. It should not be used in business logic where `Optional` would be convenient. Its quite low-level interface which main goal is to be fast. So there's no reason for `Optional` there.

You might argue that `Optional` usually can be eliminated by JIT compiler. However that's not always the case. For example, default max depth of calls for inlining in Hotspot JIT compiler is 10 and usual stream processing has more stack frames, so even one additional stack frame may prevent optimization.

Comment: Usually the `Optional` is unwrapped by the direct caller and that wouldn’t be different for the `Stream` implementation, so the other stack frames aren’t important.